# Spring Boot Cucumber org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition error

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber

I am facing following error when trying to execute Spring Boot project with cucumber. A quick search for the error tells me that i need spring-tx in my pom file. I have a question shouldn't this be taken care by spring-boot-configuration-processor, etc.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/transaction/TransactionDefinition
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.MethodScanner.scan(MethodScanner.java:40)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaBackend.loadGlue(JavaBackend.java:86)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:92)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:70)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.<init>(Runtime.java:66)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.run(Main.java:35)
    at cucumber.api.cli.Main.main(Main.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

I am basically trying to evaluate if Spring Boot is a better option with Cucumber + Selenium + API, etc instead of vanilla spring using following project https://github.com/sorin-costea/bdd

Answer (score 6):

I'm not answering about who should take care of this, but providing a solution:

I guess this is happening when you run it from **IntelliJ**, because it automatically adds spring glue.

If this is the case, just edit the *`Run/Debug Configurations`* and remove the spring reference from the glue field. Additionally you can add your StepDefs package.

To prevent it in the future, just add your Step Defs package to the Cucumber Java template, aslo under *`Run/Debug Configurations`*

Comment: Thanks @Pau . I had the same issue. It helped.